# Laravel 4 - Model properties' names different than database columns

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have one question, that seems to be logical, but I can't find answer for it.
Let's say I have Model Task:

```
class Task extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('is_done');
}
```

So, I have one property `is_done`, but when working on frontend and backend part of application, I would like to have `isDone` as model property. 
Is there a way to say it to framework, to somehow repack it for me? So that I am able to use `isDone`, throughout application, and that Model takes care of converting it to `is_done`, when it comes to saving/updating.

This would help me, so I don't have to think about names specified in database (like when using alias in traditional SQL clauses).

Is this possible at all? Does it make sense?

Comment: It looks like this is an answer, there is no built-in alternative 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571167/in-laravel-how-to-use-snake-case-for-database-table-columns-and-camel-case-for-m#answer-19572162

Answer (score 1):

To prevent writing a getter/setter methods for every single attribute of the model, you can override the magic methods from the `Eloquent` class to access them in camelCase style:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
  public function __get($key)
  {
    $snake_key = snake_case($key);
    return parent::__get($snake_key);
  }

  public function __set($key, $value)
  {
    $snake_key = snake_case($key);
    parent::__set($snake_key, $value);
  }

  public function __isset($key)
  {
    $snake_key = snake_case($key);
    return parent::__isset($snake_key);
  }

  public function __unset($key)
  {
    $snake_key = snake_case($key);
    parent::__unset($snake_key);
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved my soul man.... good one! I thought iw as going to have to use the frameworks custom getPropertyAttr($value)

Answer (score 0):

Would a getter method for your attribute help you? If yes:

```
<?php
class Task extends Eloquent {
    public function isDone()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute('is_done');
    }
}
```

If not, and you really need to access $Task->isDone: try to overwrite the $key in magic _*get() method for $key == 'isDone' (and maybe other attributes) and return the parent::*_get() with $key:

```
<?php
class Task extends Eloquent {
    public function __get($key)
    {
        if($key == 'isDone')
            $key = 'is_done';
        return parent::__get($key);
    }
}
```

And perhaps, your Eloquent needs an attribute mapper for the attribute magic methods ;)